# Selecting the column range in bash using while loop

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file named `text`: The row and columns are:

```
1   A   18  -180
2   B   19  -180
3   C   20  -150
50  D   21  -100
128 E   22  -130
140  F   23  -0
```

If we want to iterate line by line using a while loop, it would be:

```
while read -ra a; do [[ ${a[3]} != -0 ]] && ((a[3]+=42)); echo "${a[@]}"; done < file
```

The output looks like this:

```
1 A 18 -138
2 B 19 -138
3 C 20 -108
50 D 21 -58
128 E 22 -88
140 F 23 -0
```

What happened in the above line is adding `42` in each line of the 4th column except when there is `0.`

How can I want to select a number of ranges of columns using the 1st column?  For example, I want to select only `2 to 50` from the first column, which means I would like to print `2nd, 3rd and 4th` columns only.  Therefore the output would be

```
2 B 19 -138
3 C 20 -108
50 D 21 -58
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st solution:*** In case you want to print only those lines which are satisfying the condition and perform operations only on those then try following.

```
awk '$1>=2 && $1<=50{$4+=42;print}'  Input_file
```

Why `awk`? because it will be faster and is an obvious choice compare to using bash or any shell loop to process a file here.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** If OP wants to do only in shell then could try following.

```
while read first second third fourth
do
   if [[ "$first" -ge 2 && "$first" -le 50 ]]
   then
        echo "$first $second $third $((fourth+42))"
   fi
done < "Input_file"
```

Output will be as follows for above code:

```
2 B 19 -138
3 C 20 -108
50 D 21 -58
```

Comment: It looks good so far but I assume the OP wants to add the number to the 4th column *unless* the value of the 4th column is zero.

Comment: @tshiono, Thank you for your view buddy. But OP's sample output doesn't have line `128 E 22 -88` and OP mentioned like `For example, I want to select only 2 to 50 from the first column`, so I thought of this. My English is not that good :) may be I didn't get it correctly? :) OP could only confirm this.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I do agree with you. Let's wait for the OP's feedback. BR.

Answer (score 0):

Sed variant

```
sed -n "/^2 /,/^50 /p" file
```

this sed command means print(p) all lines between patterns '^2 ' and '^50 '
including lines with pattern match, symbol '^' stands for the beginning of the line.

or you can use brace expansion with `sed`

```
for i in {2..50}; { sed -n "/^$i /p" file; }
```

or with `grep`

```
for i in {2..50}; { grep "^$i " file; }
```

It's quite slow but very simple to understand, remember and use.